# REST: Filter primary resource by properties on related resource

Tags: rest, api, filter, group-by, relationship

I'm looking for some guidance/advice/input on the concept of filtering resources when making a REST API call. Let's say I have Users and Posts, and a User creates a Post. If I want to get all Posts, I might have a route as follows:

```
GET /api/posts
```

Now if I wanted to get all posts that were created after a certain date, I might add a filter parameter like so

```
GET /api/posts?created_after=2017-09-01
```

However, let's say I want to get all posts by *Users* that were created after a certain date. Is this the right format?

```
GET /api/posts?user.created_after=2017-09-01
```

When it comes to filtering, grouping, etc, I'm having a hard time figuring out the right stuff to do for REST APIs, particularly when using a paginated API. If I do this client side (which was my initial thought) then you potentially end up with a variable number of resources per page, based on what meets your criteria. It seems complicated to add all of this logic as query parameters over the API, but I can't see any other way to do it. Is there a standard for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1):

There is no objective 'right' way. If using `user.created_after` logically makes sense in the context of your API, then there's nothing really wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would not use `user.created_after`.

I would rather prefer one of the following options:

Option I: `/api/posts/users/{userid}?created_after=2017-09-01`

Option II: `/api/posts/?user={userid}&created_after=2017-09-01`

The reason is simple: It looks wrong to me to create dynamic query parameters. Instead you can combine the query parameters (Option II) or even define a more specific resource (Option I).

Regarding pagination: the standard approach is something like this: In addition to filter parameters, you define the following parameters: **page** and **pageSize**. When constructing the request, client will specify something like `page=2&pageSize=25&orderBy=creationDate`. 
It's important to note that server must always validate the parameters and can potentially ignore or override incorrect parameters (e.g. page doesn't exist, or pageSize is too big may not return an error, but instead returning reasonable output. This really depends on your business case)

Comment: There is no userid available at the beginning so:
/api/users/?created_after=2017-09-01
Will return all users created after that date.
After that you can query posts where the user id is in that list:
/api/posts/?user=[{user ids}] or a loop calling /api/posts/?user={userid}